# How to get value from header authorization bearer?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

My server give response header authorization bearer.

How can I get this value in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the $http service you can receive the headers through the success functions response object.  You can access this property through

```
$http(....).success(function(result, status, headers, config){
     var myAuthHeader = headers("myAuthorizationHeader");
 ... Do something with your headers....
    }
})
```

Comment: yes but where my authorization header? how can i get it? http://prntscr.com/7qfbwl

Comment: this is from postman http://prntscr.com/7qfeed i need thats authorization bearer, how to get it?

Comment: Updated with how to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the third parameter of the promise callback contains the response headers. You should be able to get your header from there.

Comment: yes but where my authorization header? how can i get it prntscr.com/7qfbwl